# solve equations

Tags: equation-solving

I want to find the solution of these equations:

```
x' = -3 x (-1 + x^2)/(3 (x^2) - 1) + Sqrt[3] λ x^2 (-2 + 3 x^2) y/(4*(3 (x^2) - 1))
y'=-Sqrt[3]/2  λ x y^2 + 3/2 y (1 + 1/4 x^2 (-2 + x^2) y^2)
```

`λ` is a constant parameter. I use this code to solve:

```
Solve[{X == 0, Y == 0}, {x, y}]
```

I know that must find 9 {x,y} but the solutions of this are not complete, they are Repetitious.

[image]

Comment: With \[Lambda] = 1/6; and Solve[{x' == 0, y' == 0}, {x, y}] i get a bunch of nice numeric results, so check your solve pls

Comment: Are those primes derivatives, or just decoration on your variables?

Comment: @J.M. the "difference-equations" tag explains all :)

Comment: @Dr. (titles, yecch): I don't see a recurrence anywhere in the post, so I'm tempted to remove that tag actually. ;)

Comment: @lou but i need to solution be by [Lambda]

Comment: @J.M. Be my guest

Comment: @Lou if [Lambda]=1/6 again the four result will be Repetitious. it is not true.

Comment: Check your solve X is not x

Comment: What do you mean by *they are Repetitious*. The solutions are non-degenerate. There are sign differences in the 8 non-trivial solutions that you get.

Comment: @Hubble07 i know final solution but should be derive again. true solutions are Pairwise Similar but a negative sign are different .

Answer (score 2):

Not nice, but works

```
x1 = -3 x (-1 + x^2)/(3 (x^2) - 1) + Sqrt[3] λ x^2 (-2 + 3 x^2) y/(4*(3 (x^2) - 1));
y1 = -Sqrt[3]/2 λ x y^2 + 3/2 y (1 + 1/4 x^2 (-2 + x^2) y^2);
r = Reduce[{x1 == 0, y1 == 0}, {x, y}, Backsubstitution -> True];

yv = Numerator /@ Take[Union@Flatten@ReplaceList[y, {ToRules@r}], -4]
yr = Thread[yv -> Array[yy, 4]]
yrr = Thread[yv/Sqrt[2] -> Array[yy, 4]/Sqrt[2]]
ypol = Times @@ (y - yv) // Expand

xv = Numerator /@ Take[Union@Flatten@ReplaceList[x, {ToRules@r}], -4];
xr = Thread[xv -> Array[xx, 4]]
xrr = Thread[1/xv -> 1/Array[xx, 4]];
xpol = Times @@ (x - xv) // Expand

Column@{r /. yr /. xr /. xrr /. yrr // ToRules}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Where the `xx[..]` and `yy[..]` are specified by `xr` and `yr` and are the roots of `xpol` and `ypol` respectively.